# How to add yticks label for tornado plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got this data:

|  | ses | year_dt | mentee_cnt | ses_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 11 | 2022-01-01 | 3 | 33 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 6 | 60 |
| 3 | 9 | 2022-01-01 | 16 | 144 |
| 4 | 8 | 2022-01-01 | 39 | 312 |
| 5 | 7 | 2022-01-01 | 64 | 448 |
| 6 | 6 | 2022-01-01 | 124 | 744 |
| 7 | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 191 | 955 |
| 8 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 252 | 1008 |
| 9 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 361 | 1083 |
| 10 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 368 | 736 |
| 11 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 382 | 382 |
| 12 | 0 | 2022-01-01 | 278 | 0 |
| 13 | 4 | 2021-01-01 | 2 | 8 |
| 14 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 28 | 84 |
| 15 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 103 | 206 |
| 16 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 309 | 309 |
| 17 | 0 | 2021-01-01 | 384 | 0 |

Code:

```
years = ['2021', '2022']
hight = [3, 6]

for y, h in zip(years, hight):
    df3_2_filter = df3_2[df3_2['year_dt'] == datetime.strptime(f'{y}-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()]

    pos = np.array(df3_2_filter['ses'])
    fig, (ax_left, ax_right) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(13, h))

    left = ax_left.barh(pos, df3_2_filter['mentee_cnt'], align='center', facecolor='#DEBB68', linewidth=0)
    ax_left.bar_label(left, padding=-20, size=11, label_type='edge')
    ax_left.set_xlabel('Mentee')
    ax_left.invert_xaxis()
    ax_left.set_xlim(max(df3_2_filter['mentee_cnt'])*1.1, 0)
    ax_left.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=11)
    ax_left.set_yticks([])
    ax_left.grid(False)

    right = ax_right.barh(pos, df3_2_filter['ses_amount'], align='center', facecolor='#DEBB68', linewidth=0)
    ax_right.bar_label(right, padding=0, size=11, label_type='edge')
    ax_right.set_xlabel('Sessions')
    ax_right.set_xlim(0, max(df3_2_filter['ses_amount'])*1.1)
    ax_right.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=11)
    ax_right.set_yticks(pos)
    ax_right.set_yticklabels(df3_2_filter['ses'], ha='center', x=-0.08)
    ax_right.grid(False)

    plt.suptitle(f'Mentee and sessions {y} year')
    plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: plt.show]
[image: plt.show]

How to add title for y axis for this graph?
Something like this:
[image: plt.show]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this lines:

```
ax_left.set_ylabel('Ses finished', rotation=0)
ax_left.yaxis.set_label_coords(1.1,0.02)
```

[image]